# Simplification infinite series by suppressing sums over $i$ and $j$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, power-series

I have the following expression given by
$$S_n := \sum_{0 \leq i \leq j \leq n} \frac{1}{i!(n-i)!j!(n-j)!} a^i b^{j-i} c^{n-j}. $$
I wanted to see if I could use the multinomial theorem to simplify it. It is evident that
$$\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j \leq n} \frac{1}{i!(n-i)!j!(n-j)!} a^i b^{j-i} c^{n-j} = \sum_{0 \leq i \leq j \leq n} \frac{(j-i)!}{(n-i)!j!} \cdot \frac{1}{i!(j-i)!(n-j)!} a^i b^{j-i} c^{n-j},$$
and, by the multinomial theorem, we have that
$$\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j \leq n}  \frac{1}{i!(j-i)!(n-j)!} a^i b^{j-i} c^{n-j} = \frac{1}{n!} (a+b+c)^n.$$
However, I cannot apply it directly because of the coefficients $\frac{(j-i)!}{(n-i)!j!}$. Does anyone see a way to circumvent this? I spotted an "almost multinomial type" expression in $S_n$, but feel free to utilise other results/techniques besides the multinomial theorem.

Ultimately, I'm interested in the sum
$$S:= \sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n,$$
which I'd like to write in the form $S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty T_n$ with $T_n$ only depending on $n$, thus surpassing the intermediate summations over $i$ and $j$. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe, use the fact that $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^n=\sum_{0\le i<j\le n}+\sum_{0\le j<i\le n}+\sum_{0\le i=j\le n} \; ?$$

Comment: Also note [this identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524415/on-summation-sum-k-0n-binom-nk2-xk-yn-k) for Legendre polynomials.

Comment: Prof. Burnstein thank you for your reply! The first suggestion I have already explored and, unfortunately, didn't lead to anything... I will try to see how the identity for Legendre polynomials might be helpful, as it's not clear for me atm

Comment: Maybe you are right. Redefining $S_n(a,b,c)$ by multiplying it by $(n!)^2$, this leads to $$S_n(a,b,c)+S_n\left(a,\frac{ac}{b},c\right)=\left(\frac{(a+b)(b+c)}{b}\right)^n-(c-a)^n P_n\left(\frac{c+a}{c-a}\right),$$ where $P_n$ is the $n$th Legendre polynomial. Note that $\displaystyle\frac{(a+b)(b+c)}{b}=a+b+c+\frac{ac}{b}$.

Comment: Now that you mention, if we redefine $S_n(a,b,c)$ by multiplying it by $(n!)^2$, then it's quite evident that $S_n$ becomes $$\sum_{0\leq i \leq j \leq n} \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{n - j} a^ib^{j-i} c^{n-j}.$$
By any chance, do you know if this is a known type of (multivariate) polynomial?

Comment: I haven't had this come up before. I guess you can try reducing it to considering $$\sum_{i+j\le n-1}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}x^i y^j,$$ then partition it into sub-sums where $i+j$ is constant, then use generating functions to get some variation of the Vandermonde identity. Don't know if this is going to work out, though. Maybe there is a Mathematica or Maple package to see if this has a nice closed form.